# How to know if my iot hub device exist in Azure Iot Hub?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-iot-hub

I created a device in Azure Iot Hub through Azure IOT Hub Manually in Azure Portal, is there any way we can check if a device exist in Azure Iot HUb whether it is connected or disconnected. Can anyone provide me sample code in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how you can obtain the [list of the devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory)

The query you can specify is:

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE deviceId = 'myDeviceId'
```

Here is an example of how you can execute the query with C# by using the registry manager.

```
var query = registryManager.CreateQuery(your_query, 1);
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
    foreach (var twin in page)
    {
        // do work on twin object
    }
}
```